# Update column with condition based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 6 tables in **SQL Server**, all tables are linked with each other with different criteria then I created one View which gives me a single table with all the selected category from all 6 tables, and that view table linked with my excel as pivot table.

And out of 6 tables one table called **AR1**, and in that table one column is there named **Arrear**.This column contains positive and negative number like 123, 43, 54, 0, -34, -56, -678. Now I want to bifurcate this number in category in another column in same table and column name is **OD_FD** and the condition is :

if the number >=0 then category will be **OD** 
 if the number <0 then category will be **FD**

and it should be updated automatically while appending new data.

Please explain in details as i am not expert in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this automatic population would require a trigger.

I suggest another solution. Create a view (or simply select in your query) over your `AR1` table to dynamically load your derived information like this:

```
select
    a.*,
    case
        when a.Arrear >= 0 then 'OD'
        else 'FD'
    end as OD_FD

from
    AR1 a
```